# prevent or catch active record errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
The conversion of the nvarchar value '156756756777777777' overflowed an int column.
```

Is there a best practive way to catch the above active record error?  This can occur with url tampering and a user trying to access an invalid id.

I am already using:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :rescue_not_found
```

which catches records not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `find_by_id`, which will return `nil` instead of throwing error.

Or `where(:id => 123).first`, which will return `nil`, if record doesn't exist

**NOTE:** Rails 4 syntax for these finders is:

```
Post.find_by({ :id => 123 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the following to the ApplicationController>

rescue_from Exception, :with => :rescue_not_found